# Why is the wrong route being used?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I am trying to do what SO does for its Question controller.

- `/Posts/{id}/{title}` when viewing a post (action name not shown)
- `/Posts/New` when you are posting something new.
- `/Posts/Delete/10`  etc....

I have two routes set up (well, one if you don't count the default). What appears to be happening is all actions in the Post controller are being routed through the first one.

What is that? I obviously have it wrong, but I can't figure this out.

```
routes.MapRoute("ViewPosts",
    "Posts/{postid}/{title}",
    new { controller = "Posts", action = "View", postid = "", title = "" });

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first route handles all your requests which starts from `/Posts`.

You need to use constraints to allow `{postid}` be only number:

```
routes.MapRoute("ViewPosts",
    "Posts/{postid}/{title}",
    new { controller = "Posts", action = "View", postid = "", title = "" },
    new { postid= @"\d+" });
```

In this case only if numeric Id is provided this route will handle it, otherwise "Default" route will handle.

Comment: What happens with `/Posts` with that rule, and no other? It would still match. (which may or may not be the intent)

Comment: This rule will still work. The constraints is defined only on `{postid}` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, that sort of worked. (well, no errors are thrown). However, now actions like `/edit/10` are showing up `/edit?id=10`

Comment: Try to use `RouteLink` instead of `ActionLink` with specifying "Default" route directly in it.

Answer (score 1):

All routes are going through the first because you have not specified that the `postid` field can only be numeric, or defined an earlier route that will catch `/Posts/New`. It is passing `New` as the `postid` with the `View` action.

You can add this route definition *before* the ones you have now:

```
routes.MapRoute("NewPost",
    "Posts/New",
    new{controller="Posts", action="New"});
```

Or whatever the appropriate controller/action would be.

Comment: Do I need to have a route for every other action in that controller then?

Comment: Maybe just one that catches all non-postid routes and sends them to the appropriately-named Action. Like `routes.MapRoute("OtherPost", "Posts/{action}/{id}", new{controller="Posts"}, new{action="^[^0-9]"});` which would catch all URLs that do not start with a number, leaving those to fall through to the existing one.